# Branches of $\arg(z)$ and $\log(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I do not understand this excerpt from my textbook:

[image]

It says that any open disk G that excludes the origin, G has a branch. But in the problem, it says there is no such branch? I do not understand the wording.

Comment: I agree that the wording is misleading. I think it means that any point within the inner ring of a disc is also "within" the disc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "open disk that excludes the origin" is something like 
$$
\{z : |z-2| < 1 \}
$$
-- and open disk centered at $2$, with radius $1$. The point $z = 0$ is not in this set. If I'd written
$$
\{z : |z-2| < 3 \}
$$
it would be an open disk that DOES include the origin.

The set given in Exercise IV.10.1 is not a open disk -- it's annulus (one that happens to "enclose" the origin).

I think perhaps your confusion might be that you're reading "open disk, with the origin removed" for "open disk that excludes the origin," but I may be misunderstanding.

Regardless, the claim is that on certain open disks --- those in which the origin is not one of the points --- the branch is defined. The set in the exercise is not an open disk, so there's no contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I was reading it as 'disk centered at {0} but not including {0}.' Just to be clear, does this mean (1) this branch property **never** holds for an open disk that includes the origin, and that (2) for **every** open disk that does not contain {0}, there is a branch of arg z and log z?

Comment: Both of those statements are true (assuming "this branch property" means "there's a well-defined function "arg" with the property that ..."). I'm not sure that I can say that "this means that...", because I don't know what "this" is, precisely. But both statements are indeed true.

Comment: I have a small question please, I read on a copybook about complex numbers, a sentence that said "if $z$ is a real number then $$arg z= 0, \pi$$ deprived of the denominator". And a similar one "if $z$ is pure immaginary then $$arg z= \pm \pi/2$$, deprived of the numerator and denominator". Any idea what could this possibly mean? Thanks in advance ... By the way I am just asking about the sentence "deprived of ..."

Comment: I have no idea what those "deprived of" clauses mean. Perhaps the book is a translation, and these are translation errors?